# Paginate an array with multiple filters

Tags: search, pagination, params

I'm looking to paginate and array with multiple filters.

The current url would be: `www.example.com/search?filter=shorts&type=leather&brand=sams`

Clicking on the next next link returns: `www.example.com/search/p2` effectively removing the search params.

Is there a way to paginate the full url without removing the search params?

```
{% paginate test.limit(4) as entries %}
    {% for entry in entriesOnPage %}
        <article>
            <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
            {{ entry.body }}
        </article>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.prevUrl %}
        <a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>
    {% endif %}

    {% if paginate.nextUrl %}
        <a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this (completely untested):

```
{% if paginate.prevUrl %}
    <a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}?{{ craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath() }}">Previous Page</a>
{% endif %}

{% if paginate.nextUrl %}
    <a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}?{{ craft.request.getQueryStringWithoutPath() }}">Next Page</a>
{% endif %}
```

**Update:**

The above will only work once Craft 2.3 comes out.

In the meantime, it's a bit sketchy, but you can open up `craft/app/variables/HttpRequestVariable.php` and add this method:

```
public function getQueryStringWithoutPath()
{
    return craft()->request->getQueryStringWithoutPath();
}
```

And it should work.  But please be aware that file could be overwritten by a 2.2 build release at any point during an auto-update and your template would break.

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Throws this error: 'Method "getQueryStringWithoutPath" for object "Craft\HttpRequestVariable" does not exist'

Comment: Gah... just realized that got added to the unreleased Craft 2.3.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Hacking the core? That's some back-alley advice right there Brad. ;)

Comment: HACK THE PLANET

Comment: TBH, the OP can (and should) put that method into a custom plugin. Should work just as well, right?

Comment: Good point... will be much safer for updating.